# How to check from a program in background if key or combination was pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app which will type text on mouse point; even if that means switching window focus to some other program, such as notepad.

I'm trying to be able to press some key combination to start/stop typing.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use Keyboard hooks, you can find many examples by googling it.

here is an example from codeproject.com:

[keyboardhook.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx)